# Crear N registros en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo 2 tablas que son PAGO_CABECERA y PAGO_DETALLE, el caso es que el detalle esta vacio, tengo que agregar los registros desde la cabecera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como el caso del ID de cabecera 1, tengo 4 MESES_PAGADOS, entonces se debe de agregar 4 registros a la tabla PAGO_DETALLE y en la columna DETALLE_PAGO por cada registro agregado aumentar 1 mes a la FECHA_PRIMER_PAGO

he creado una logica pero dependo de dos ciclos while, 1 para recorrer el PAGO_CABECERA y el otro para recorrer MESES_PAGADOS

```
WHILE @ContadorMesVigencia <= @ContadorTotalMesesVigencia
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #MOVIMIENTOSFECHASACUMULADOS (CodigoDocumento,FechaProceso,Monto,MontoPagado,Estado,EstadoPagado)
        VALUES (@CodigoDocumento, @FechaInicioVigenciaF, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        SET @FechaInicioVigenciaF = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @FechaInicioVigenciaF)
        SET @ContadorMesVigencia = @ContadorMesVigencia + 1
    END
```

esto hace que la bd consuma demasiado y el tiempo que toma en ejecutarlo es mucho.

Comment: Interesante... Tiene sentido que tome mucho tiempo para ejecutarse... Las bases de datos relacionales están diseñadas para trabajar según la teoría de conjuntos... Estás utilizándolo para iterar de forma anidada lo que resulta en una complejidad cuadrática... Tarda mucho? Sí... Esperabas algo diferente?

Comment: si, buscar una forma de no depender del while, crear una tabla dinamica

Comment: buscando informacion  vi que puedes crear registros con WITH 
pero no se como darle el valor default que tengo en mi tabla, el with lo multiplica  10*10 100*100 llegando hasta los 10k

Answer (score 1):

Para este tipo de consultas, existe lo que se llama tabla de números o *Tally Table* en inglés. Básicamente es una tabla con una sola columna con números consecutivos. Puedes tener tablas físicas o crearlas al vuelo como en este ejemplo.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT *
FROM cteTally
```

Teniendo esta tabla, solo tienes que unirla con un non-equi JOIN para generar las filas necesarias. Esta tabla genera hasta 10,000 números por iteración, pero puede cambiar el valor según sea necesario.

Al final, así queda el código de ejemplo.

```
CREATE TABLE PAGO_CABECERA(
    ID  int,
    Meses_Pagados int,
    Fecha_Primer_Pago date)
INSERT INTO PAGO_CABECERA
VALUES( 1, 4, '20220101'), 
      ( 4, 2, '20200701');

WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY p.ID, t.n) AS ID, -- Esto es para simular el autoincrementable
    p.ID AS ID_CABECERA,
    DATEADD( MM, n - 1, Fecha_Primer_Pago) -- Restamos uno para no sumar en la primer fila.
FROM PAGO_CABECERA p
JOIN cteTally t ON p.Meses_Pagados >= t.n
ORDER BY 2, 3;
```